# How did "djēm" avoid palatalization?

Tags: language-evolution, phonology, proto-italic, italic-languages

While posting an answer to [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5815/406), I looked back at [an answer I'd written on another site](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/31744/10559), which mentions the strange case of Latin *diēs* < PIt **diēm*.

In particular:

> The *accusative* form of [the Proto-Indo-European root behind *Zeús* and *Juppiter*], **dyēm* (cf AGrk *Zēn*), *also* survived in Latin, in the form **diēm* > *diem*. Uniquely, the *dy* here didn't become **dj* > *j*; some scholars suggest that it evolved in a different Italic language/dialect, which didn't have the palatalization rules, then got borrowed back into Latin.

But, to my shame, I can't seem to figure out who these "some scholars" I cited actually are: I recently lost my web history, and with it all records of which particular articles I'd been reading.

And so I'm asking here: how did **diēm* avoid the palatalization that created *Jovis*? I was under the impression that this palatalization happened back in Proto-Italic times, before Latin had split off; was there actually some Italic language that avoided the process entirely, from which Latin could have borrowed an unpalatalized **diēm*? And if not, where could this [notorious exception](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2526/how-does-the-initial-consonant-in-jupiter-and-zeus-come-from-the-d-in-pie/31744#comment6765_2526) have come from?

Comment: Did you ever find those scholars again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Diem* seems to be due not to borrowing, but to Lindeman's Law. This is a reconstructed rule of PIE whereby monosyllabic words beginning with a stop+sonorant cluster (CR-) could optionally insert the vowel equivalent of the sonorant between C and R.

So in this case, a monosyllable *di̯ēm would have two alternative forms: *di̯ēm and *dii̯ēm, where the second is the "Lindeman variant".

Now in Latin, *di̯- became *j*-, but *di- stayed intact. So *diem* can be explained as the reflex of the Lindeman variant, while *Jovis* etc. come from the *di̯- forms.